# SQL server Invalid object name 'TableName' SSMS , Table in system

Tags: sql, ssms

I am working on SQL Server Management Studio. I wish to open a table that is already in SSMS. I am getting below error. The table is reflecting in my tables.

**Database**: Consumer Complaints contains **2 tables**: dbo.Consumer_Complaints and dbo.RAW P9-ConsumerComplaints. 
I am trying to open dbo.Consumer_Complaints table.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.Consumer_Complaints'.

Completion time: 2020-04-22T10:17:50.5134070+05:30
```

[image]

Steps tried so far:

`CTR` + `SHIFT` + `R` in the query window

Also I went to `Edit` -> `Intellisense` -> `Refresh local cache` after putting curser in the query window. Still no result

EDIT: after comments

`SELECT * FROM [Consumer Complaints]` this also has error

```
   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'Consumer 
   Complaints
```

Comment: You need to select appropriate database name under which this table Consumer_Complaints is present . You can do it by clicking on drop down present at top left of SSMS

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Consumer Complaints]` this also has error `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Consumer Complaints'.`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor. . . Do you know under which database this object exists ? If yes then select that database first then execute query againt that database.

Comment: hi as you can see in image, Consumer Cmplaints is the database which contains dbo.Consumer_Complaints table and few other tables

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor. . . You need to first select the database name located at the left side of top.

Comment: pls tell the commands and answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to execute query over "Master" database. You can change current database on the UI
[image]

or add SQL query:

```
USE 'Consumer Cmplaints'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first select the database name :

```
use [Consumer Complaints]

select * from dbo.Consumer_Complaints
```

However, you can also run the select statement with this :

```
select *
from [Consumer Complaints].dbo.Consumer_Complaints
```

Answer (score 1):

Te to run 
Use [Consumer Complaints]
before your select statement so as to let smss know which database scheme to use